# Magento 2 : How to Override \Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\CompanyQuoteConfigRepository.php

Tags: magento2, override-model, magento-ee, magento2-b2b

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\CompanyQuoteConfigRepository" type="Test\CompanyQuoteConfig\Model\CompanyQuoteConfigRepository" /> 
</config>
```

Class

```
namespace Test\CompanyQuoteConfig\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\CompanyQuoteConfigRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\Data\CompanyQuoteConfigInterface;
use Magento\NegotiableQuote\Api\Data\CompanyQuoteConfigInterfaceFactory;

class CompanyQuoteConfigRepository extends \Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\CompanyQuoteConfigRepository
{
    /**
     * Company quote config factory.
     *
     * @var CompanyQuoteConfigInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $companyQuoteConfigFactory;

    /**
     * Company quote config resource
     *
     * @var Magento\NegotiableQuote\Model\ResourceModel\CompanyQuoteConfig $companyQuoteConfigResource
     */
    protected $companyQuoteConfigResource;

    /**
     * @param CompanyQuoteConfigInterfaceFactory $companyQuoteConfigFactory
     * @param ResourceModel\CompanyQuoteConfig $companyQuoteConfigResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        CompanyQuoteConfigInterfaceFactory $companyQuoteConfigFactory,
        ResourceModel\CompanyQuoteConfig $companyQuoteConfigResource
    ) {
        parent::__construct($companyQuoteConfigFactory, $companyQuoteConfigResource);
    }
    public function save(CompanyQuoteConfigInterface $quoteConfig)
    {
        try {
            $this->companyQuoteConfigResource->save($quoteConfig);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            //throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('There was an error saving company quote config.'));
            throw new CouldNotSaveException($exception->getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: I am getting the error "There was an error saving company quote config."  while creating a customer, so wanted to check what is going wrong.